# System Freezes for 5 Seconds Whenever a New Bluetooth Device or USB Device Is Connected

Tags: 20.04, usb, bluetooth, cinnamon

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.11.0-25. If I connect a Bluetooth device (e.g. my keyboard after going to sleep or a new USB device, but not SD cards) the system will freeze for around 5 seconds. Audio will keep playing, but the image is frozen and the mouse/etc will not work.

Unfortunately I cannot show any code or ideas.

How can I solve this problem?

A list of devices currently connected to my machine via BT:

- Audiolab Amp
- Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard (will timeout every 5mins of no use)

````javascript
hutber@hutber:~$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 5C:F3:70:A7:97:F3  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:1772646 acl:6128 sco:0 events:225073 errors:0
    TX bytes:378842911 acl:443999 sco:0 commands:892 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'hutber'
    Class: 0x1c0104
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x1000
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x220e
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)

hutber@hutber:~$ dmesg | grep -I bluetooth
[   82.887791] input: Audiolab Omnia BT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:68/0005:000A:FFFF.000B/input/input25
[30789.688109] input: Audiolab Omnia BT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:65/0005:000A:FFFF.0012/input/input46
[132984.840315] input: Audiolab Omnia BT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:65/0005:000A:FFFF.0017/input/input65
[133224.134540] input: Audiolab Omnia BT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:65/0005:000A:FFFF.0018/input/input67
[168916.269875] input: Audiolab Omnia BT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:71/0005:000A:FFFF.0019/input/input69
[169359.710382] input: Audiolab Omnia BT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:65/0005:000A:FFFF.001B/input/input75
[205453.272541] input: Audiolab Omnia BT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:71/0005:000A:FFFF.001C/input/input77
[205470.351280] input: Audiolab Omnia BT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:68/0005:000A:FFFF.001E/input/input83
[250641.646597] input: Audiolab Omnia BT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:71/0005:000A:FFFF.0021/input/input93
[250660.044110] input: Audiolab Omnia BT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:68/0005:000A:FFFF.0023/input/input99
[263990.825430] input: Audiolab Omnia BT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:000A:FFFF.0029/input/input121
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo lsusb
[sudo] password for hutber:  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0732 Genesys Logic, Inc. All-in-One Cardreader
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 058f:8468 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 17e9:6006 DisplayLink 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0b05:18a3 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB2.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1b1c:0c04 Corsair Link Cooling Node
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 06c4:c411 Bizlink International Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 046d:0892 Logitech, Inc. OrbiCam
Bus 001 Device 030: ID 2109:0101 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 028: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1532:007e Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 1532:0088 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 046d:0ab7 Logitech, Inc. Blue Microphones
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 0b05:17cb ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0922:001f Dymo-CoStar Corp. DYMO LabelWriter 4XL
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

[Edit]
I replaced my entire machine, motherboard/ram/gpu/cpu/fan etc and the issue is still occuring.
````

Comment: Have you made any changes in your BIOS? Can you try resetting it to defaults and disable `Fastboot` & `Secureboot` ? Does your system freezes with every peripheral or USB devices when connecting your system, this can be hardware specific as well. Since the information you have given is very limited, these are just the ones that come to my mind :)

Comment: Then I shall be running these tests later this evening :) thank you

Comment: So it seems secure boot is greyed out with the value 'enabled' so no hope to change this. Fast boot is indeed disabled. OS type is dry to "Other OS" if they helps us at all.

Comment: Hmm, afaik secure boot should be disabled it can cause issues sometimes, best to disable that. Never heard of OS type but seems irrelevant, are you using a laptop if so which model? Can you try to burn a new iso into a usb drive and boot to live environment and play around, let's see if it's hardware/bios issue.

Comment: It's a desktop machine, Asus mother board. Booting into live disc!!! Genius god, why didn't I think of that. I'm annoyingly out of the country for 9 days now and my bounty will close!! Feel free to give some information and I'll gladly award the bounty and try to trouble shot when I'm back

Comment: I've just done a fresh install of 20.04 and can confirm the issue is still happening. Which makes me think its a hardware thing? I will try a new dongle.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of: (1) `dmesg | grep -I bluetooth` (2) `sudo lsusb` and (3) `hciconfig -a`? With this, it may be possible to identify an issue 

Comment: Thanks you @matigo I've updated the question with all 3 of these.

Comment: This is interesting. The `1532:0088` Razer shows as being a Bluetooth device, and the Asus does not appear to be in the `dmesg` output. Have you installed the requisite driver for the Asus device? 

Comment: Ye, I didn't realise the Razer mouse would be bluetooth :O However there no official drivers for Asus's dongle. My idea was to get a broadcom device and then support would be out of the box

Comment: Final question before I write a possible solution: do you see any messages in `/var/log/syslog` when you plug the Asus Bluetooth dongle into the machine? Could you [edit] your question to include that output, as it will confirm a couple of things, allowing for a slightly customised answer 

Comment: I have cleared syslog and then plugged in and then back in, but syslog does not get updated when I do this. So I guess its either in a different log, or somehow the world has gone crazy :D Thank you again for helping!

Comment: Sadly nobody has suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is problem with BIOS or hardware. Just update the BIOS and later change the hardware if updating the BIOS doesn't work.

*I would also recommend you to update you system

Edit : Assuming all drivers are installed properly BIOS should be the issue as some have experienced freezing issue and got solved when BIOS was updated. Maybe it is the problem with the driver not the hardware or BIOS so if updating BIOS doesn't work install proprietary drivers.

(Personally don't there is a problem with your install) Also with Try a fresh install with version 21.10 downloaded freshly from Official Ubuntu site. I think there might be some issues with 20.04 ISO you have or flashing tool. Use Etcher tool and don't see any reason else you might encounter this issue.
Check this Link for More Support (ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) On official Ubuntu site there is proper step by step way which you can follow easily. Ubuntu officially also recommends Etcher over Rufus or other tools as it is easy

Comment: Hello. I see a guess here but not an answer.

Comment: @David Edited my answer. I hope now it is more useful

Comment: Also found something on BCM20702A0 on launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/906832

Comment: Thanks for looking. However the link you suggest says bluetooth does not work. But it is working for me :D It just freezes the machine for around 5 seconds when connecting to a new bluetooth device.

Comment: @JamieHutber The like is old, Did you update your BIOS?

Comment: I did update the BIOS and it actually broke my machine. So I just had to fork out £2k to buy a new one! lol I am not running via the builtin HDMI. Sad times!! But I can confirm, the issue is still there.