# System hangs randomly for a few seconds when bluetooth headphones are connected

Tags: sound, bluetooth, freeze, headphones

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.13.0-44. When I connect my Bluetooth headphones everything appears to be working as usual and then at randomly intervals, or what appear to be random to me, my system will freeze for around 5 seconds. Audio will keep playing, but the image is frozen and the mouse/etc will not work.

Unfortunately I cannot show any code or ideas.

How can I solve this problem?

A list of devices currently connected to my machine via BT:

Sony WF-1000XM4

What I find interesting is that, when my amp is connected, this issue does not occur. `Audiolab Omnia BT`. Could it be a case of multiple devices connected at the same time?

I have had issues with this before on a different issue: [System Freezes for 5 Seconds Whenever a New Bluetooth Device or USB Device Is Connected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356582/system-freezes-for-5-seconds-whenever-a-new-bluetooth-device-or-usb-device-is-co) which was not resolved, but could or could not be related.

Comment: Note the exact time of a hang. Then review your logs for the seconds around that time. Your previous question seemed to have nothing in the logs, which suggested a possible (non-Ubuntu) hardware issue. Also see if the issue occurs when connecting to other folks' hardware.

Comment: Thanks! Which logs would I be looking for? The location if possible please.